# Get logs of bash code from bash subprocess

Tags: python, bash

I'm running some bash codes from python using subprocess module, E.G.

```
import subprocess
container_logs = 'az container logs --name textgeneratorinference'

subprocess.call([container_logs],shell=True)
```

From there I get a 0 response meaning the code was executed, but when I run the same come in the terminal I get a message E.G:

```
Login Succeeded
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in .
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
```

How can I get this into a python variable?

Comment: @Mihir you are right, thanks I'll close it

Comment: Some of those strings look like they will be on standard error. Tangentially see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess